# Is the order of NVIDIA kernel modules in mkinitcpio important?

Tags: linux, mkinitcpio

I'm troubleshooting a solution for Nvidia screen tearing cited on the [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#Tearing.2FBroken_VSync) which instructs to enable [DRM kernel mode setting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting):

> *nvidia 364.16 adds support for DRM kernel mode setting. To enable this
>   feature, add the nvidia-drm.modeset=1 kernel parameter, and add
>   **nvidia, nvidia_modeset, nvidia_uvm and nvidia_drm** to your initramfs#MODULES.*

I entered the MODULES into `mkinitcpio.conf` [as instructed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting). Here is the relevant line from my `.conf` file: `MODULES="ext4 dm_mod dm_crypt vfat nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm"`

Troubleshooting, I discovered evidence the modules are not loaded:

```
$ rmmod nvidia_drm nvidia_modeset nvidia
rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia_drm is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia_modeset is not currently loaded
```

I know mkinitcpio HOOKS go in order (ie. LUKS). **Is the order of NVIDIA kernel modules in mkinitcpio important?**

Answer (score 1):

I think that your syntax is wrong.

The `MODULES` variable [is an array](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#MODULES), so assigning to it should be done using `(...)`:

```
MODULES=(ext4 dm_mod dm_crypt vfat nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm)
```